# Should I use all the Bootstrap classes for a responsive website?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It is maybe a very noob question, but I wanted to know that should I use all the Bootstrap grid classes?

I mean if I had a **very good** UI design for desktop and for mobile.Is it enough to use only the `col-sm-*` and the `col-xs-*` classes, or I have to use the `col-md-*` and the `col-lg-*` classes too?

I ask that question, because I used to read some webpages source code and I often see this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  //some content
</div>
```

But wasn't it enough to use just the `sm` and the `xs` classes for this?

Comment: If your `col` goes same for all device, say 6, then you should just use `col-xs-6`.

Comment: From the docs: *"Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-\* class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg-\* class is not present."* That means there's no point in specifying different sizes if they're all the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, you can just use

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
```

And each element with this class will always have 50% width, no matter the viewport...

A bit more information:

As BootStrap is mobile-first, if you plan on keeping elements 50% and next to each other from 768px and up, you can just use `col-sm-6` for example, there's no need to put all other `lg` / `md`'s in there.

But let's say you want elements to be 50% width from 768px to 991px and 33.333333% from 992px and up, you can do:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    // content
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    // content
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    // content
</div>
```

FYI - The `col-xs-12` will kick in at 767px and below, meaning each element will then span 100% width.

The above could therefore be written like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    // content
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    // content
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    // content
</div>
```

And exactly the same behaivour will be applied as the `col-sm-6` will span 100% at 767px and below anyway!

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you need to do in your page.
No, it's not needed to use all `col` classes to make it responsive because in bootstrap all the lowest classes are by default `col-*-12` and the next ones will have the same value.

let's say you have this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  //some content
</div>
```

That mean:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  //some content
</div>
```

so in your example you have to use only `col-xs-6`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use **all** of the bootstrap column classes. If you can support your desired design and user experience, then the fewer classes the better. Use as many classes as needed to get the desired result.

For example, I've written many apps that only have a single breakpoint. (`col-sm-6`), such that the design only has a breakpoint between desktop and tablet devices. These are simpler to debug, and if you're on a time budget, allows you to put more effort into your most popular devices.

*Short answer: Only use as many bootstrap grid classes are you need to get your desired website layout on each device you wish to support.*